# Issue placing div after facebook friends box

Tags: asp.net, css, facebook, html

Every time I include the code for the facebook friends like box the div element box below it goes wacky. I cannot control where its positioned. It either disappears or overlaps a different div. Originally I just wanted specials, events, then fbFriends in a row then the box div below the three divs. I have been trying to wrap the divs to control everything better but am still unsuccessful. Any help would be appreciated

specials  events  fbFriends

box -------------------box

```
<div id="specialsWrapper">
        <div id="specials" ><p>Featured Specials</p></div>
        <div id="events" ><p>What's happening at the hub</p></div>
        <div id="fbFriends">
            <div  class="fb-like-box" 
                data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/********" 
                data-height="395" data-width="250" data-show-faces="true" 
                data-colorscheme="dark" data-stream="false" data-header="true" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="box" ></div>

#specialsWrapper
{
    height: 450px;
    width: 920px;
    color: white;
}

#specials {
    float: left;
    border:2px dashed white; 
    height:390px;
    width: 270px;
    color: white;
    margin: 25px 10px 0px 48px;
}

#specials p {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 15px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-style: oblique;
}


#events {
    float: left;
    border:2px dashed white; 
    height:390px;
    width: 270px;
    color: white;
    margin: 25px 15px 15px 15px;
}

#events p {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 15px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-style: oblique;
}

#fbFriends {
    float: left;
    margin: 25px 15px 15px 15px;
    width: 250px;
    height:390px; 
}

#box
{
    clear: left;
    border: 2px dashed white;
    height: 60px;
    width: 853px;
    color: white;
    margin: 25px 15px 15px 48px;
}
```

Comment: can you give some link with working example?

Comment: No but i added a screenshot of what I want to achieve. What is the best way to do this using float? Is wrapping necessary? Even using the wrapping the box div doesnt not move down no matter how much margin i add to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's anwser for your question
[EXAMPLE ON CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/SzymonDziewonski/pen/npeCt)

Your build of these box's is weird thats why I had to use `top: 40px;` with `position: relative;`

btw. that's how you do on jsfiddle or codepen exampl, thats all community ask. Spend 5 min for your question isnt much to ask?

hope thats help.

**EDIT:**

I found what what the issue, you didnt closed specialsWrapper div thats why margin dint work.
I also cancel margin-botton from boxes inside specialWrapper and put overflow: auto to specialWrapper to countheight.
Now top: no need to be writen.

Comment: That helps but why is my build weird? Please explain since I want to do it right. And trust me i spent 10 minutes on this question. JSfiddle and codepen are new to me

Comment: Shoot i do have it closed in my project. Just missed it on the question so that isnt the answer

Comment: @osiris355 for me weird was that you could use inline-block instead float: left , cuz inline-block count height not like float.
Now margin works as you can see in example (edited) box has 45px margin top and it doesnt stuck as you said on madmanali93 anwser

Comment: So going forward use inline-block instead of float?

Comment: I'm not saying that's the only way cuz the same effect i accomplish in your example with adding overflow: auto but i prefer to use inline-block as much it is possitble. As a matter of fact it deppends from you :). Hope my anwser helps you, peace :)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you might want it display: inline-block; but without something to see I can't really know what's going on. And your description isn't enough. Could you post what's going on  on js.fiddle.net or give us an example site?

Comment: I added a screenshot but i will mess with jsfiddle as well. Basically the bottom rectangle element is stuck. I cannot add margin to move it down and I dont know why

Comment: Try adding a padding. I thought the screenshot is of what to be achieved and not what is really going on. Let me know when you have the link up. I will be able to help more then.